# Can I use JHipster to create a react frontend with a microservice backend?

Tags: jhipster

With jhipster I can use the monolith style application to create a react frontend that calls into a spring backend. Is there a way to create a react frontend that calls in to a microservice backend?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. Have you read the docs about JHipster gateways ?

Comment: The answer to my question is "read the jhipster gateway docs". Thank you. Or more verbosely, "a microservices gateway create the app front end and a backend gateway layer the front end invokes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I'd missed this but the answer is here https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-microservices/

### Generating entities in a microservices architecture

Using the entity sub-generator works a little bit differently in a microservices architecture, as the front-end and the back-end codes are not located in the same application.

First, generate the entities in the microservices applications: this works as usual, and you can also use JHipster UML or JDL Studio to help you generate complex entities and relationships. As microservices don’t have a front-end, no Angular/React code will be generated.

Then, on the gateway(s), run the entity sub-generator again. A new question will appear at the beginning, which is specific to gateways:

You will have the choice either to generate an new entity normally (a gateway is also a standard JHipster application, so this would work like for a monolith application), or use an existing JHipster configuration from a microservice.
If you choose to generate the entity from a microservice, you will need to enter the path to this microservice on your local computer, and then JHipster will generate the front-end code on the gateway.